# Active Directory commands work under PowerShell but not with command prompt

Tags: windows, perl, powershell, active-directory, command-prompt

Active Directory commands issued by my Perl script are working from PowerShell but not when I run it from the command prompt.

Is there any way to run these commands from the command prompt?

The commands that I am using are `dsadd`, `dsrm`, `dsmod` etc.

Comment: Also  I forget to mention that I am using ssh object to run the commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that the `PATH` environment variable doesn't include the directory where the Active Directory tools are stored

To find where they are on your system, under PowerShell enter

```
where.exe dsadd
```

This will show the full path to `dsadd`

If you just use `where`, as normal, then PowerShell will use the `where` cmdlet which is an entirely different thing.

If you then modify the `PATH` variable on the command prompt to include the path revealed above, Active Directory commands will work just as they do on PowerShell